# Assign model object to TextBoxFor dynamically inside a For loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to display 45 text boxes all based on a objects in the model.  I'm wondering if I can do this inside a loop instead of coding it out 44 times (which wouldn't be the worst thing ever... just looking for a shortcut.)

```
@for (int y = 0; y < 44; y++)
{
    <div class="row">
        @Html.Label(y + 1 + " Years Old: ", new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm col-md-9">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.LeadPricingModel.MinYearBuilt_0, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", style = "width:100px;" })
        </div>
     </div>
}
```

The label works great.  But, what I'm trying to do is make the `_0` in `MinYearBuilt_0` based on `y`.  Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You are going to have to make the MinYearBuilt an array or List however (if it already isn't). Make sure if it's an array to initialize it to be large enough for 45 objects.

```
@for (int y = 0; y < 44; y++)
{
  <div class="row">
    @Html.Label(y + 1 + " Years Old: ", new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm class=" col-md-9"">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.LeadPricingModel.MinYearBuilt[y], new { @class = "form-control input-sm", style = "width:100px;" })
    </div>
 </div>
}
```

Comment: Ok, good idea.  Yeah this will take some re-working of the object, as it's currently not an array.  I'm just saving the entire object in the DB as a JSON blob, so I'll have to figure out which will be faster... re-work the object, or just code out 45 TextBoxFor's.  Thanks!